# systemd-analyze gives "No such property 'FirmwareTimestampMonotonic'" error

Tags: systemd

running systemd-analyze gives me the error message:

```
Failed to parse reply: No such property 'FirmwareTimestampMonotonic'
```

How can I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing systemd-sysv. Once I installed it and rebooted, all was right with the world.